# zend framework 2 error after moving to centOS

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hi I've encountered an error after moving my zend framework 2 application from xampp to centOS PC

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\\Navigation\\Tsettings' not found in /var/www/html/eziroster/module/Application/src/Application/Navigation/TSettingsFactory.php on line 13, referer: http://dev24.skytill.com.au/eziroster/public/login`

do I need to change something when transferring to another server?

Comment: File names on Linux are case sensitive. Make sure that your filename and class name match exactly..

Comment: yes they are as it is.

Comment: The class looked for is `Tsettings` and your filename is `TSettings....`. If you have checked the case-sensitivity issue of the class file then you must have mentioned `....\Tsettings` somewhere in the `config` file.

Comment: thanks I've double checked it and it worked.